# How to establish a hasManyThrough relationship in laravel for roles and permissions?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, has-many-through

So I understand how to load the roles for a user and the permissions for a role.

But now I have a `user` table, a `role` table, and a `permission` table. I also have `role_user` table for linking users and roles. And of course a `permission_role` for linking permissions and roles.

Now when I want to get all the roles for the user, I simply do something like this:

```
public function roles()
{
        return $this->belongsToMany('Uppdragshuset\AO\Tenant\Models\Role');
}
```

Similarly I can fetch permissions for roles like so:

```
public function permissions()
{
        return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class);
}
```

Now according to the documentation on laravel, I can directly fetch permissions for a user by using the hasManyThrough relation too like so:

```
public function permissions()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Permission::class, Role::class);
}
```

But this is returning with an error saying:

> Unknown column 'role.user_id' in 'field list'

I think I understand why. Laravel is looking for `user_id` field in the `role` table but it does not understand that it is a many to many relation and it should look for it in the pivot table.

So what is the way around this? Is there a way around this in Eloquent or will I have to resort to using the query builder? And if yes, how to do the same thing with the query builder?

Comment: Note that the naming convention for tables is the plural of the model. So instead of `user` you should have `users`. Same applies for other tables.

Comment: I know about that. Which is why I have over ridden the names in the respective models.

Comment: @Rohan did you try morphToMany method?

Comment: No I haven't. I am not sure how to use that here tho.

Answer (score 0):

`HasManyThrough` can only be used to connect two `HasMany` relationships. There is no native relationship for your case.

I created a `HasManyThrough` relationship with unlimited levels and support for `BelongsToMany`:
[Repository on GitHub](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep)

After the installation, you can use it like this:

```php
class User extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function permissions() {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(Permission::class, ['role_user', Role::class, 'permission_role']);
    }
}
```